# First loop restarting in recursive function php

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, pdo, while-loop

I'm trying to create a series of `<ul>` and `<li>` to create a directory/file structure to navigate some files created from a table in a dB. The table (tb_lib_manual) contains both files and folders.

If a record has a null entry for fileID then it is a folder not a file. each record has a parentID to show which folder is parent, for files and folders in the root this is 0.

The php code is thus:

```
class library_folders extends system_pageElement 
{
    private $html = '';
    private $i = 0;
    private $stmtArray = array();
    private $objectArray = array();

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->nextList();
    }


    function nextList($parentID = 0) 
    {
        $qSQL = 'SELECT * FROM tb_lib_manual WHERE parentID=:parentID';
        $stmtArray[$this->i] = $this->dbConnection->prepare($qSQL);
        $stmtArray[$this->i]->bindValue(':parentID', $parentID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmtArray[$this->i]->execute();
        if($stmtArray[$this->i]->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $display ='';
            if($parentID != 0)
            {
                $display = ' style="display:none"';
            }
            $this->html .= '<ul' . $display . '>';
        }


        while ($this->objectArray[$this->i] = $stmtArray[$this->i]->fetchObject()) 
        {
            $this->html .= '<li>' . $this->objectArray[$this->i]->title;
            if($this->objectArray[$this->i]->fileID == null)
            {
                //we have a folder!
                $manualID = $this->objectArray[$this->i]->manualID;
                $this->i ++;
                $this->nextList($manualID);
                $this->i--;
            }
            $this->html .= '</li>';
        }


        if($stmtArray[$this->i]->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $this->html .= '</ul>';
        }   

        echo $this->html;
    }   
function __destruct()
    {
        parent::__destruct();
    }

}
```

The problem is when the code returns back to the while loop after calling itself it restarts the loop rather than carrying on where it left off, causing a repeat in the child folder. Is there either a better way to do this or am I doing something wrong!?

Table looks like this:

[image]

output like this:
'

- A Manual
- A Manual
- Folder 1

  Nasa exercise

- A Manual
- A Manual
- Folder 1

  Nasa exercise

'

Comment: is manualID the same as ParentID?

Comment: yes it is sorry should've explained, obviously different columns...

Comment: You might place some debug output of the variables like `var_dump($manualID);`.

Comment: Hi sorry have no idea how to place output of debug as I can't get my debug to work (aptana studio 3) however the table data looks like this (just edited question)

Comment: I'm more interested in what's in `$this->objectArray`. I think we're missing the other important parts of the class

Comment: Hi fair comment have added whole class

Comment: As a side remark (much to the side and really a point of detail from a semantic-nazi) : better use `<ol>` than `<ul>` as your list is most probably ordered (alphabetically I guess) and it would make little sense (or at least be highly un-friendly) to have it randomly ordered...

Comment: Thank you all for comments, I've realised the mistake, I think the code works, the problem was where I put the echo, I've moved to the last line of the constructor and bingo! Thanks you basti for your answer, unfortunately I don't understand it - yet... Although I can see that multiple queries on the dB are bad, I wasn't anticipating too much data in the table...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the code, very silly mistake, echo in the wrong place...

```
class library_folders extends system_pageElement 
{
    private $html = '';
    private $i = 0;
    private $stmtArray = array();
    private $objectArray = array();

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->nextList();

        echo $this->html;

    }


    function nextList($parentID = 0) 
    {
        $qSQL = 'SELECT * FROM tb_lib_manual WHERE parentID=:parentID';
        //echo $this->i;        
        $stmtArray[$this->i] = $this->dbConnection->prepare($qSQL);
        $stmtArray[$this->i]->bindValue(':parentID', $parentID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmtArray[$this->i]->execute();
        if($stmtArray[$this->i]->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $this->html .= '<ul>';
        }

        while ($this->objectArray[$this->i] = $stmtArray[$this->i]->fetchObject()) 
        {
            $this->html .= '<li>' . $this->objectArray[$this->i]->title;
            if($this->objectArray[$this->i]->fileID == null)
            {
                //we have a folder!
                $manualID = $this->objectArray[$this->i]->manualID;
                $this->i ++;
                $this->nextList($manualID);
                $this->i--;
            }
            $this->html .= '</li>';
        }


        if($stmtArray[$this->i]->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $this->html .= '</ul>';
        }   

    }   

    function __destruct()
    {
        parent::__destruct();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are better ways of doing this.

**If you fetch the whole tree every time**, you might as well load all the nodes into a big array (of objects), put each node's id as index and then loop over the array once to create the parent references by for example

```
// create a fake root node to start your traversal later on
// only do this if you don't have a real root node 
// which I assume you don't
$root = (object) ["children" => []];

// loop over all nodes
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
    // if the node has a parent node that is not root
    if ($node->parentId > 0)
    {
         // put it into it's parent's list of children
         $nodes[ $node->parentId ]->children[] = $node;
    }
    else
    {
         // otherwise put it into root's list of children
         $root->children[] = $node;
    }
}
```

Complexity: You do one query and you have to iterate all your nodes once.

For this to work your nodes need to be objects. Otherwise each assignment to `$node->children` will create a copy of the assigned node where you wanted a reference.

**If you do not want to fetch all nodes**, you can go through your tree level by level by creating a list of node ids from the previous level.

```
function fetchLevel ($nodes, $previousLevelIds)
{
    // get all children from the previous level's nodes
    // I assume $previousLevelIds to be an array of integers. beware of sql injection
    // I refrained from using prepared statements for simplicity
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id, parentId FROM nodes WHERE parentId IN (".implode(",",$previousLevelIds).")");

    // fetch nodes as instances of stdclass
    $currentLevelNodes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $nextLevelIds = [];
    foreach ($currentLevelNodes as $node)
    {
         // ids for next level
         $nextLevelIds[] = $node->id;

         // parent <-> child reference
         $nodes[ $node->parentId ]->children[] = $node;
    }

    // fetch the next level only if we found any nodes in this level
    // this will stop the recursion
    if ($nextLevelIds)
        fetchLevel($nodes, $nextLevelIds);
}

// start by using a fake root again
$root = (object) ["id" => 0, "children" => []];
$nodes = [0 => $root];
fetchLevel($nodes, [0]);

// or start with a specific node in the tree
$node = $pdo->query("SELECT id, parentId FROM nodes WHERE id = 1337")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$nodes = [$node->id => $node];
fetchLevel($nodes, [$node->id]);

// or a number of nodes which don't even have to 
// be on the same level, but you might fetch nodes multiple times
// if you it this way
```

Complexity: Number of queries <= height of your tree. You only iterate each fetched node once.

**For displaying the tree as html list** you iterate once more:

```
class Foo {

    public $html;

    public function getList ($nodes)
    {
         // outer most ul
         $this->html = '<ul>';

         $this->recurseList($nodes);

         $this->html .= '</ul>';
    }

    protected function recurseList ($nodes)
    {
        foreach ($nodes as $node)
        {
            $this->html .= "<li><span>".$node->name."</span>";

            if ($node->children)
            {
                if ($node->parentId > 0)
                    $this->html .= '<ul style="display:none">';
                else
                    $this->html .= '<ul>';

                $this->recurseList($node->children);

                $this->html .= "</ul>";
            }

            $this->html .= "</li>";
        }
    }
}
```

Some unrelated remarks:

- instead of a hard-coded `style="display:none"` you could just use a css rule like `ul li ul {display:none}` to hide all lists below root
- I split fetching the data from the database and converting the data for displaying into two separate scripts, which is the standard when you develop using [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). If you don't want to do this run the scripts in succession.
- PHP itself is a template engine, but consider using another template engine to display your html like [Smarty](http://smarty.net). I personally prefer smarty for it's simpler syntax.
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) answer on how to bind a PHP array to a MySQL IN-operator using prepared statements
- if you need to fetch subtrees often consider using [a special table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model#Example) structure to reduce the number of queries

Comment: Thanks Basti, fixed my code, but I think I'm starting to see why your solution is better, but I don't understand it fully yet as I'm a novice...

Comment: If you are interested to learn and have questions, just ask away. Since you found the problem in your code yourself, put your own answer explaining it and accept it. ;-)